# Text file to DataFrame using HTML tags

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, beautifulsoup

**Background:**
I recently scraped a popular recipe website for each of the recipe following information:

1. Name
2. Cook time
3. Yield time
4. Ingredients

**Note:** the file also contains other information, however I'm only concerned with the above.

**Code used:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from splinter import Browser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import selenium
import time
import csv

driver=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.simplyrecipes.com/index/"
driver.get(url) 
driver.maximize_window()

response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

linklist=[]
links=soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    linklist.append(link)
linklist_text=[]
for i in range(164,1068):
    linklist_text.append(linklist[i].text)
    
recipe_list=[]

for link in linklist_text[616 :]:
    time.sleep(0.3)
    target=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(link)
    target.click()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    cards = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("grd-title-link")
    for i in range(0,len(cards)):
        try:
            newcards = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("grd-title-link")
            time.sleep(0.3)
            newcards[i].click()
            time.sleep(0.3)
            recipe=driver.find_element_by_id("sr-recipe-callout")
            recipe_list.append(recipe.text)
            driver.back()
            time.sleep(0.3)
        except:
            continue

    nxt=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rpg-next")
    if len(nxt) > 0:
        pages=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rpg-page-numbers")
        textpages=pages[-2].text
        lastpage=int(textpages)
        for i in range(1,lastpage):
            nxt2=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rpg-next")
            time.sleep(0.3)
            try:
                nxt2[0].click()
                cards2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("grd-title-link")
                for i in range(0,len(cards2)):
                    try:
                        newcards2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("grd-title-link")
                        time.sleep(0.3)
                        newcards2[i].click()
                        time.sleep(0.3)
                        recipe=driver.find_element_by_id("sr-recipe-callout")
                        recipe_list.append(recipe.text)
                        driver.back()
                        time.sleep(0.3)
                    except:
                        continue
            except:
                continue
    with open ("recipe_list2.txt", "a") as fout:
        for recipe_text in recipe_list:
            fout.write("%s\n" % recipe_text.encode("utf-8"))
    recipe_list=[]
            
    driver.get(url)
```

**Code Output (text file):**
The output of this scrape is a text file with the following format. **Note:** the below example has two recipes (the file would be unruly long, to post on here) and is organized by recipe per line:

**Output example:**

```
b'Print\nHow To Make Fast, No-Soak Beans in the Instant Pot\nCook time: 30 minutesYield: about 5 cups cooked beans\nDon\'t skip the olive oil. This helps reduce foam during cooking, which could clog the pressure valve on the pressure cooker.\nIf cooking red kidney beans, I recommend boiling the beans for about 10 minutes first to break down the lectins.\nINGREDIENTS\n1 pound dried beans (see below for cooking times for specific beans)\n8 cups water\n1 tablespoon olive oil\n1 to 2 teaspoons salt\n2 o 3 cloves peeled garlic, optional\n1 bay leaf, optional\nSpecial equipment:\n6- to 8-quart pressure cooker (I use a 6-quart Instant Pot)\nMETHODHIDE PHOTOS\n1 Combine all ingredients in the pressure cooker. Do not fill the pressure cooker more than half full.\n2 Secure the lid. Make sure the pressure regulator valve is closed. (On an Instant Pot, this means it will be set to the the "sealing" position.)\n3 Cook the beans: Here are the cooking times for unsoaked beans in the Instant Pot. Cooking times will be similar for other electric pressure cookers; cooking time will be slightly less for stovetop pressure cookers. Double-check the manual that came with your pressure cooker for more exact cooking times:\nBlack beans: 20 to 25 minutes\nBlack-eyed peas : 20 to 25 minutes\nGreat Northern beans: 25 to 30 minutes\nNavy beans: 25 to 30 minutes\nPinto beans: 25 to 30 minutes\nCannellini beans: 35 to 40 minutes\nChickpeas (garbanzo beans): 35 to 40 minutes\nRed kidney beans: 25-30 minutes (boil for 10 minutes before pressure cooking)\nCook beans at high pressure for the time recommended above. The pressure cooker will take 15 to 20 minutes to come to full pressure before cooking begins.\n4 Let the pressure release: Once cooking is complete, you can let the pressure release naturally on its own, which takes about 20 to 30 minutes, or you can do a "quick release" by opening the pressure valve on the top of the pressure cooker. If doing a rapid release, be careful because the bean liquid sometimes foams into the valve.\nI recommend letting the pressure release naturally for as long as you\'re able before the beans are needed. This helps the beans retain their shape and avoids the bean liquid foaming.\nWhat to do if your beans aren\'t quite done: Put the lid back on the pressure cooker and make sure the release valve is set back to "sealing." Cook at high pressure for another 5 to 10 minutes (depending on if you think your beans need just a little more time or a little more time to finish). The pot will quickly come back up to pressure because the contents are already hot. Check your beans after the extra cooking time and continue cooking for longer if needed.\n5 Using and storing your beans: The beans can be strained and used right away, or cooled and stored in their cooking liquid. They will keep for up to a week refrigerated or up to 3 months in the freezer.\nHello! All photos and content are copyright protected. Please do not use our photos without prior written permission. Thank you!\nPrint'
b'Print\nPinto Beans with Bacon and Jalape\xc3\xb1os Recipe\nPrep time: 5 minutesCook time: 25 minutesYield: Serves 4-6\nINGREDIENTS\n1 tablespoon extra virgin olive oil\n2 to 3 whole jalape\xc3\xb1o chile peppers\n2 to 3 thick-cut slices of bacon\n2 cups of chopped onion\n2 medium clove of garlic, minced\n4 cups of cooked pinto beans (2 15-ounce cans, rinsed and drained)\nSalt\n1/2 cup, loosely packed, chopped fresh cilantro\nMETHOD\n1 Cook and prep jalape\xc3\xb1os: Heat oil in a medium skillet on high heat. Put the jalape\xc3\xb1os in the pan and stir to coat with the oil. Let cook, turning occasionally, on all sides, until all sides are nicely browned (about 10-15 minutes, depending on how hot your burner is).\nRemove from pan. Cut away and discard the stem, core, seeds, and veins. Coarsely chop the remaining jalape\xc3\xb1o flesh.\n2 Cook bacon: While the jalape\xc3\xb1os are cooking, cook the bacon slices on medium low heat in a large skillet, until crispy. Remove bacon from the pan to a paper towel-lined plate. Pour off (do not discard down the drain!) all but 2 tablespoons of bacon fat.\n3 Cook onion in bacon fat: Add the chopped onion to the pan with the bacon fat. Increase the heat to medium high and cook until translucent and lightly browned. Add the minced garlic and cook a minute more. While the onion is cooking, chop the cooked bacon.\n4 Add the cooked beans, chopped bacon, and the chopped jalape\xc3\xb1os to the pan and stir to mix. Sprinkle with salt.\nServe with chopped fresh cilantro, and steak and salsa.\nHello! All photos and content are copyright protected. Please do not use our photos without prior written permission. Thank you!\nPrint'
```

**Expected DataFrame:**
I am trying to break up the code, so it has the following pandas DataFrame format, again using the above two recipes as the example:

```
                                                Recipe              Cook time                 Yield                                     INGREDIENTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

    How To Make Fast, No-Soak Beans in the Instant Pot              25 minutes            Serves 4-6          1 tablespoon extra virgin olive oil...
    Pinto Beans with Bacon and Jalape\xc3\xb1os Recipe              30 minutes         5 cups cooked                          1 pound dried beans...
```

**What I've discovered thus far:**
I have looked at the format of the text file and have been able to identify that I need to do the following:

- Recipe - extract everything after `b'Print\n` up until the next instance of `\n`
- Cook time - extract everything after `\nCook time:` up until the next instance of `\n`
- Yield - extract everything after `Yield:`  up until the next instance of `\n`
- Ingredients - extract everything after `\nINGREDIENTS\n` up until the next instance of `\nMETHODHIDE`
  I would be very grateful for any suggestions on how I might go about coding something in Python to do this.

Comment: replace('Print","") then split the lines on "\n". line.split("\n") this will give you an array split by your desired columns and append all these lines to a new list "lines_array"), then df = pd.DataFrame(lines_array,columns = ["Recipe","cook time",.......])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a fan of regular expressions for tasks like this. We can make use of named capture groups.

```
import re

raw_recipes = [
    b'Print\nHow To Make Fast, No-Soak Beans in the Instant Pot\nCook time: 30 minutesYield: about 5 cups cooked beans\nDon\'t skip the olive oil. This helps reduce foam during cooking, which could clog the pressure valve on the pressure cooker.\nIf cooking red kidney beans, I recommend boiling the beans for about 10 minutes first to break down the lectins.\nINGREDIENTS\n1 pound dried beans (see below for cooking times for specific beans)\n8 cups water\n1 tablespoon olive oil\n1 to 2 teaspoons salt\n2 o 3 cloves peeled garlic, optional\n1 bay leaf, optional\nSpecial equipment:\n6- to 8-quart pressure cooker (I use a 6-quart Instant Pot)\nMETHODHIDE PHOTOS\n1 Combine all ingredients in the pressure cooker. Do not fill the pressure cooker more than half full.\n2 Secure the lid. Make sure the pressure regulator valve is closed. (On an Instant Pot, this means it will be set to the the "sealing" position.)\n3 Cook the beans: Here are the cooking times for unsoaked beans in the Instant Pot. Cooking times will be similar for other electric pressure cookers; cooking time will be slightly less for stovetop pressure cookers. Double-check the manual that came with your pressure cooker for more exact cooking times:\nBlack beans: 20 to 25 minutes\nBlack-eyed peas : 20 to 25 minutes\nGreat Northern beans: 25 to 30 minutes\nNavy beans: 25 to 30 minutes\nPinto beans: 25 to 30 minutes\nCannellini beans: 35 to 40 minutes\nChickpeas (garbanzo beans): 35 to 40 minutes\nRed kidney beans: 25-30 minutes (boil for 10 minutes before pressure cooking)\nCook beans at high pressure for the time recommended above. The pressure cooker will take 15 to 20 minutes to come to full pressure before cooking begins.\n4 Let the pressure release: Once cooking is complete, you can let the pressure release naturally on its own, which takes about 20 to 30 minutes, or you can do a "quick release" by opening the pressure valve on the top of the pressure cooker. If doing a rapid release, be careful because the bean liquid sometimes foams into the valve.\nI recommend letting the pressure release naturally for as long as you\'re able before the beans are needed. This helps the beans retain their shape and avoids the bean liquid foaming.\nWhat to do if your beans aren\'t quite done: Put the lid back on the pressure cooker and make sure the release valve is set back to "sealing." Cook at high pressure for another 5 to 10 minutes (depending on if you think your beans need just a little more time or a little more time to finish). The pot will quickly come back up to pressure because the contents are already hot. Check your beans after the extra cooking time and continue cooking for longer if needed.\n5 Using and storing your beans: The beans can be strained and used right away, or cooled and stored in their cooking liquid. They will keep for up to a week refrigerated or up to 3 months in the freezer.\nHello! All photos and content are copyright protected. Please do not use our photos without prior written permission. Thank you!\nPrint'
    b'Print\nPinto Beans with Bacon and Jalape\xc3\xb1os Recipe\nPrep time: 5 minutesCook time: 25 minutesYield: Serves 4-6\nINGREDIENTS\n1 tablespoon extra virgin olive oil\n2 to 3 whole jalape\xc3\xb1o chile peppers\n2 to 3 thick-cut slices of bacon\n2 cups of chopped onion\n2 medium clove of garlic, minced\n4 cups of cooked pinto beans (2 15-ounce cans, rinsed and drained)\nSalt\n1/2 cup, loosely packed, chopped fresh cilantro\nMETHOD\n1 Cook and prep jalape\xc3\xb1os: Heat oil in a medium skillet on high heat. Put the jalape\xc3\xb1os in the pan and stir to coat with the oil. Let cook, turning occasionally, on all sides, until all sides are nicely browned (about 10-15 minutes, depending on how hot your burner is).\nRemove from pan. Cut away and discard the stem, core, seeds, and veins. Coarsely chop the remaining jalape\xc3\xb1o flesh.\n2 Cook bacon: While the jalape\xc3\xb1os are cooking, cook the bacon slices on medium low heat in a large skillet, until crispy. Remove bacon from the pan to a paper towel-lined plate. Pour off (do not discard down the drain!) all but 2 tablespoons of bacon fat.\n3 Cook onion in bacon fat: Add the chopped onion to the pan with the bacon fat. Increase the heat to medium high and cook until translucent and lightly browned. Add the minced garlic and cook a minute more. While the onion is cooking, chop the cooked bacon.\n4 Add the cooked beans, chopped bacon, and the chopped jalape\xc3\xb1os to the pan and stir to mix. Sprinkle with salt.\nServe with chopped fresh cilantro, and steak and salsa.\nHello! All photos and content are copyright protected. Please do not use our photos without prior written permission. Thank you!\nPrint'
]
recipes = []

regex = r"Print\n(?P<recipe>.*)\n(.|\n)*Cook time: (?P<cook_time>.*)Yield: (?P<yield>.*)\n(.|\n)*\nINGREDIENTS\n(?P<ingredients>(.|\n)*)\nMETHODHIDE"

for recipe in raw_recipes:
    m = re.match(regex, recipe.decode())
    if isinstance(m, re.Match):
        recipes.append(m.groupdict())
```